# iptables - drop all HTTP(S) traffic but from CloudFlare

Tags: iptables, http, ddos, block, cloudflare

I would like to allow only HTTP(S) traffic coming from CloudFlare. In that way attackers cannot attack the server directly. 
I know CloudFlare is not mainly a DDoS mitigator, but I would like to try it either way.

I'm currently only having access to iptables (ipv4 only), but will try to install ip6tables soon. I just need to have this fixed soon. (we're getting (D)DoSed atm.)

I was thinking about something like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s <CloudFlare IP> --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s <CloudFlare IP> --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

I know that CloudFlare has multiple IPs, but just for an example.

Would this be the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that would work. You can also use ! to negate like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT ! -s <cloud_flare ip> -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT ! -s <cloud_flare ip> -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

Comment: Ah great, I didn't know about that. 
Is it also possible to use that with multiple IPs? I need to accept about 10 IP ranges from CloudFlare.

Comment: From the manpage: Multiple addresses can be specified, but this will expand to multiple rules (when adding with -A), or will cause multiple rules to be deleted (with -D).

Comment: so like:
`iptables -I INPUT ! -s <cloud_flare ip1> -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP`
`iptables -I INPUT ! -s <cloud_flare ip2> -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP`?

Comment: Sorry, obviously it's not possible to give many addresses when used with !, you'll have to create multiple rules.

Comment: Haha okay, no problem!

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please mark it as accepted answer, so I can get that sweet reputation :)

Comment: Will do, sorry ;)